# Responsive barchart

Tags: angular, typescript, responsive-design, chart.js, bar-chart

I am using chart.js and am trying to make the barthickness vary as per the screenwidth

I have written a function in which the variable holds the value of the screen and decides the width and based on that width I have written if else logic

This piece of code I have written in app.service.ts globally

```
public checkWidth() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width <= 768)
 {
        this.screenWidth = 'sm';
        this.onMobileChange(true);
    } 
else if (width > 768 && width <= 992)
 {
        this.screenWidth = 'md';
        this.onMobileChange(false);
    } 
else {
        this.screenWidth = 'lg';
        this.onMobileChange(false);
    }
}
```

And I used this piece of code in my file which has barchart.

```
public checkWidth() 
{
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        if (width <= 1000)
 {
this.newBarThickness = 15;
            } else 
{
            this.newBarThickness  = 27;
           }
        }
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: The barthickness din't pick up the values which I gave. Now it's working fine! I have changed my code little bit and it worked, thanks for the response @AkberIqbal

Comment: Can you please answer my p-dropdown question which I am still stuck at! @AkberIqbal

Comment: A minimal stackblitz will make it easier for me to help...

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, don't know how stackblitz. I guess you are asking my code snippet. If yes, here it is,                                                                         
                                                                                                                        <span class="ddMargin">
 
      <p-dropdown class= "ddMargin-dropdown" [autoWidth]="false" appendTo="body" [options]="allCustomers" [(ngModel)]="selectedCustomer" [filter]="true"
        (onChange)="getCurrentCustomer($event)" >
      </p-dropdown>
    </span>

Comment: Stackblitz.com is super simple - lets you put up a complete angular app in no time... This way, the community can see what is going on and help with specific areas that you need help with

Comment: Oh, unfortunately I can't put the whole angular app. I can provide this piece of code for now. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: In my earlier comment, I asked that you share a minimal stackblitz - this can be a time saver for all